# How to highlight an image after selection using css or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple images in a page that is selectable by user. User can select any image by simply click on that image.

One solution would be to add border to that image but border is already applied on all images.

How can i highlight that image after selection?

In particular, how can i highlight selected image using css or jquery?

Comment: Several effects are widely used to mark an image as "selected". Changing the `border-color` could be one, but also setting the `opacity` or adding an in-place `box-shadow`.

Comment: Are you asking what to do to show the user the image is selected, your question sound of topic for SO as it seemes to be more related to UX than code. You should ask at http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: is there any other way except border-color, box-shadow and opacity

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about user experience and not about code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

#### css: use the box-shadow to pop the selected image-

```
img{border:solid 1px red; margin:10px;}
.selected{
   box-shadow:0px 12px 22px 1px #333;
}
```

#### jquery:

```
$('img').click(function(){
   $('.selected').removeClass('selected'); // removes the previous selected class
   $(this).addClass('selected'); // adds the class to the clicked image
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hP3JH/)

Answer (score 2):

add a class to selected images, and use css to style that class:

```
$('img').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('selectedIMG');
 });
```

then in css:

```
img.selectedIMG{
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: i mention in my question that i already have border on all images

Comment: you can just "add" to your existing style. Say, if img{} already has `border: 2px lime`, you can set `border-color: red`, which will overwrite just the color. The most "specific" rule wins in CSS, which means `img` is applied first, and `img.selectedIMG` would be applied later (and then overwrite previous styles).

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if you like this but i suggest to use `zoom` like this:

**css**

```
img {
    border: solid 1px red;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.imgActive{
    zoom: 1.1;
}
```

**js**

```
$("img").on("click",
            function(){
                $(this).toggleClass("imgActive");
            });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Hndr/5/)

Answer (score 0):

(since it's tagged with jQuery, i'll answer with a jQuery example)

script:

```
$('img').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

please note that the selector is overly broad, this would mean _ALL_IMAGES_ANYWHERE_. You can easily scope it like this `$('#gallery img')` if you only want images inside `#gallery`

css:

```
img {
    border: 5px solid lime;
}

img.selected {
    border-color: red; /* will overwrite color, only */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : place green border on the clicked image. (assumption - default border is red)

```
$(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){
      $('img').removeClass('focused');
      $(this).addClass('focused');
    });
});
```

CSS :

```
img {border: 1px solid red;}// default border
.focused{border: 1px solid green;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QA2Ec/19/)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it's possible to do that in pure CSS.

Here is a jQuery solution

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/jVEc7/

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Photo 1"/>

<img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Photo 2"/>

<img src="http://placekitten.com/280/280" alt="Photo 3"/>
```

**CSS**

```
img{border: solid 1px red;}
.active_img{border: solid 2px blue;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $("img").on("click",function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("active_img");
    })
});
```

I you want to force to select maximum 1 element, you can use the `removeClass` jQuery method and then add the `active_img` class to the clicked element.